# assigning new columns to data frame via `assign`

Tags: r, assign

So I have this data frame `df`:

```
df<-data.frame(a=runif(10),b=sample(10),c=c(1,2,3,NA,1,2,1,4,5,3))

> head(df,2)
             a  b  c
1  0.503718016  4  1
2  0.253538589 10  2
```

So for the case where:

```
 >df$a_new<-NA
 > head(df,2)
             a  b  c a_new
1  0.503718016  4  1  NA
2  0.253538589 10  2  NA
```

I then thought of a quick and dirty solution of creating objects with peculiar names such as: `df$XXX_new` and why not attributing values via `assign`(Of course `XXX` represents a variable that runs over a vector of names, namely `names(df)`:

```
for(ll in names(df))
  assign(paste0("df$",ll,"_new"),NA)
```

I was expecting *new* columns to appear to my old `df`. This is not the case.

```
>head(df)
             a  b  c a_new
1  0.503718016  4  1  NA
2  0.253538589 10  2  NA
```

Is there an explanation as to why this occurs?

Comment: Do you expect to have `a_new`, `b_new`, and `c_new`?

Comment: @akrun yes indeed

Comment: `for(ll in names(df)) df[,paste0(ll,"_new")] <- NA` will achieve what you are looking for, but I'm not sure why your method behaves as it does!

Comment: @AndrewGustar understood your example. how about using `assign()`?

Comment: The help text for `assign` says that 'There are no restrictions on the name given as x: it can be a non-syntactic name', so presumably there is no way it will recognise that the `$` character means you want it to work within a df.  You could certainly cause some confusion with these names!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `assign`, the first argument is 'x' - which is a variable name given as a character string.  Here, the "df" is the object name of the data.frame.  As second argument, we assign, the new variable to the `value` i.e. NA

```
for(ll in names(df)) assign("df", `[<-`(df, paste0(ll, "_new"), value = NA))
head(df, 2)
#          a b c a_new b_new c_new
#1 0.2925740 7 1    NA    NA    NA
#2 0.2248911 4 2    NA    NA    NA
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df<-data.frame(a=runif(10),b=sample(10),c=c(1,2,3,NA,1,2,1,4,5,3))
```